# how to define embed player height in fluid design to keep the aspect ratio? (when width is 100%)

Tags: html, css, embed, fluid, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to treat embed players like images in a fluid design?

I usually set the width of images to 100%, and let the browser calculate the height (modern browsers scale pictures with the original aspect ratio).

That's not the case with the `<embed>` element. I realize that the video information isn't given, but it should be available somehow, without fixed pixel values. In most cases only 16:9 and 4:3 aspect-ratios are used. If just those two values could be added, it would be a great help.

With `width="100%"` and/or `style="width: 100%;"` the embedded video fills the container properly (horizontally). **The height should be (width/4*3) or (width/16*9)** but as far as I know there's no way to calculate it.

I'd prefer a solution without inline styles, and even though the height and width attributes are required/recommended I don't like to add any specified length values in HTML. A CSS solution or a "secret" parameter for the embedded video would be ideal. If there's a youtube-specific solution, that's enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked perfectly for me.

http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

^ CSS only liquid youtube embed dimensions.

With this you can completely remove the height and width attributes of the iframe.  It will automatically fit it's parent container's width.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jQuery. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var width = $('div').width();
var ratio = 16/9;
var height = width/ratio + 32; /* 32px is approx. height of controls */
$('iframe').css('height', height);
```

You would, however have to do it on window.resize aswell, if you want that functionality.

Comment: thanks! i've tried it, but there's a problem. if i use `width="100%"` or `style="width: 100%;"` the jquery `.width()` translates it to 100px, so the height is 56.25px everytime... it should measure the width instead of using the given percent number as pixel value.

Comment: You could wrap the iframe in a div and then get the width from that instead. See example here. http://jsfiddle.net/hRatJ/

Comment: Why JavaScript when [it can be done in pure CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/)?

Answer (score 0):

also, check out this little jQuery plugin by über-guru Chris Coyer: http://fitvidsjs.com

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this for a project in which I had an embedded youtube video centered on the page on top of a background image which was set to display 100vh x 100vh minus a bit of space for a header and stickynav bar.  It was important that the youtube video not only scale but maintain a precise 30 pixel margin from the bottom of the image.

So I set the size of the background image on page load relative to the size of the window and define the dimensions of the iframe within the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function which is called by the Youtube API only after the frame is loaded.  I've also got the same function on window resize so that it will scale fluidly if you resize the browser window.

Since the vertical margin was an important issue I started with the height, setting the height of the iframe based on the height of the background image minus the space needed for margins.  I then manually calculated the 16:9 aspect ratio for the width by dividing the height by 9 and multiplying by 16.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var content = $('#hero');
    var contentH = $(window).height() - 158;
    var contentW = $(window).width();
    content.css('height',contentH);
} );
$(window).resize(function() {
    var content = $('#hero');
    var iframe = $('.videoWrapper iframe');
    var contentH = $(window).height() - 158;
    var iframeH = contentH - 150;
    content.css('height',contentH);
    iframe.css('height',iframeH);
    var iframeW = iframeH/9 * 16;
    iframe.css('width',iframeW);
    var margin = ($(window).width() - iframeW) / 2;
    $('.videoWrapper').style.marginLeft = margin;
} );

<div id="hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <hgroup class="span12 text-center" role="heading">
                <h1></h1>
                <h2></h2>
            </hgroup>
            <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
            <center>
                <div class="videoWrapper">
                    <div id="player"></div>
                </div>
            </center>
            <script>
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    videoId:'xxxxxxxxx',playerVars: {
                        controls:0,enablejsapi:1,iv_load_policy:3
                    }
                } );
                var content = $('#hero');
                var iframe = $('.videoWrapper iframe');
                var contentH = $(window).height() - 158;
                var contentW = $(window).width();
                var iframeH = contentH - 150;
                iframe.css('height',iframeH);
                var iframeW = iframeH/9 * 16;
                iframe.css('width',iframeW);
            }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```